# Serializing a single enum value, honoring `EnumMember` attributes

Tags: c#, enums, data-annotations

I have the following types:

```cs
[DataContract]
public enum Foo
{
    Unknown,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Fix")]
    Foo,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Bax")]
    Bar
}

[DataContract]
public class Baz
{
    [DataMember]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

This works as expected:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new StringEnumConverter() }
};
var serializedBaz = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Baz { Foo = Foo.Foo } }, jsonSettings);

Console.WriteLine(serializedBaz);
// {"Foo":"Fix"}
```

However, this doesn't:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Foo.Foo, jsonSettings);
// "Fix"
```

In other words, when serializing the enum value by itself, I get the quotation marks as part of the value. If I use `ToString()`, it uses the names of the enum values, rather than the values specified in `[EnumMember]`, i.e. `Foo` instead of `Fix`. Is there a way to get at `Fix` (neither `Foo` nor `"Fix"`) without having to write my own extension method?